# Extract value from a string using Regex C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I will know if it's possible to extract value(int) from a string with regex in C#.

For example, i have some datas like :

> "124521test45125 100KG10 fdfdfdf"
>
> "9856745test123456 60ML450 fdfdfdf"

I will like to extract value which contain caracters "KG" and "ML" with numbers which are before and after this caracters.

The result will be "100KG10" and "60ML450".

It is possible that they don't have numbers after like this :

> "124521test45125 100KG fdfdfdf"

The result for this case will be "100KG".

I use this method to extract value :

```
public static string Test(string str)
        {
            Regex regex = new Regex(@"???REGEX??");
            Match match = regex.Match(str);
            if (match.Success)
                return match.Value;

            return match;
        }
```

The problem is i just start to learn Regex and i don't know  how i can extract only this value.

Could any one help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you carry on learning and try something first

Comment: \\d if for a number in regex. You could look for something like "\\dKG\\d"

Comment: I would recommend something like regex101.com for easier testing [`[0-9]*(KG|ML)[0-9]*`](https://regex101.com/r/sRhYnu/1)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest the pattern to be

```
 [0-9]+(KG|ML)[0-9]*
```

where

- `[0-9]+` one or more digits
- `(KG|ML)`followed by either `KG` or `ML`
- `[0-9]*` followed by zero or more digits

The implementation can be

```
public static string Test(string str) {
  // public methods should validate their values; null string is a case
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
    return null;

  var match = Regex.Match(str, @"[0-9]+(KG|ML)[0-9]*");

  return match.Success ? match.Value : null;
}
```

Comment: will fail in case of `ML` it must be `(KG|ML)` instead of `(KG)|(ML)`

Answer (score 1):

RegEx

```
public static string Test(string str)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d+(ML|KG)\d*");
    Match match = regex.Match(str);
    if (match.Success)
        return match.Value;

    return null;
}
```

Comment: `match` is of type `Match` when method must return `string`; change second `return match;` to `return null;`, `return ""` etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] arrayResult = input.Split(' ').Where(x=>x.Contains("ML") || x.Contains("KG")).ToArray();

string result = string.Join(", ", arrayResult);
```

Here without regex.

**EDIT:** After the comment:

```
    public static bool Condition(string x)
    {
        bool check1 = x.Contains("ML");
        bool check2 = x.Contains("KG");
        bool result = false;

        if(check1)
        {
            x = x.Replace("ML", "");

            var arr = x.Where(y => !char.IsDigit(y));

            result = arr.Count() == 0;
        }
        else if(check2)
        {
            x = x.Replace("KG", "");

            var arr = x.Where(y => !char.IsDigit(y));

            result = arr.Count() == 0;

        }

        return result;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input = "124521teKGst45125 100KG10 fdfdfdf";

        string[] arrayResult = input.Split(' ').Where(x => Condition(x)).ToArray();

        string result = string.Join(", ", arrayResult);
    }
```

Comment: Will fail in case of `"124521teKGst45125 100KG10 fdfdfdf"`

Comment: @Toshi yes but his examples are not like this and specially for you I wrote you an edit :)