# How to use RegEx expression in utilFindInResponse FiddlerScript

Tags: fiddler

I want to find the string "wallet":10000000, and use `oSession.utilFindInResponse(/"wallet":([0-9.]+),/,0);` but return -1.

How do I use regular expressions to search for a string FiddlerScript?

Answer (score 0):

`oSession.utilFindInResponse` is according to the [Fiddler documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/fiddlercore/api/fiddler.session#collapsible-Fiddler_Session_utilFindInResponse_System_String_System_Boolean_) defined to perform a string search. Regular expressions are not mentioned and thus not supported using this command.

Assuming the response consists of text (e.g. a html page or a JSON file) you can get the response body as String and the apply the standard .Net commands for regular expression search:

```
var bodyString = oSession.GetResponseBodyAsString();
var regex = /\"wallet\":([0-9.]+)/;
if (regex.test(bodyString)) {
   ... 
}
```

Comment: How to get a value ([0-9.]+) to change it and write it to the body? thanks

Comment: @Роман You can do so using regular .Net code, e.g. as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41061087/150978

Comment: I'm a beginner , please help me        
its string - {"balance":99800,"bet":998,}

my code:


`var bodyString = oSession.GetResponseBodyAsString();
            var bal = /\"balance\":(.+?),/;
   var bet = /\"bet\":(.+?),/;
   var result=bal-bet;
            //oSession.utilReplaceInResponse('"balance:"','"balance:"'+result);
            var directory = "D:\\openserver\\domains\\test1.ru\\";
            var path3: String = System.IO.Path.Combine(directory, "ba1.txt");   
            oSession.SaveResponseBody(path3);`

Comment: @Роман Please do not post code in comments, because of formatting the code becomes unreadable. Also your question is solved. If you still something does not work please post another question and this time describe in detail what you want to achieve. Last but not least in comments please always include the `@username` to which user you answer, otherwise the user don't get any notification and thus will most likely not answer.

Comment: thank you for helping me. I beat the question.

Comment: @Роман The common way on Stackoverflow to say thank you is to upvote an answer and optionally accept the answer (the green checkmark on the left side). Because of your reputation score you can at the moment only vote on answers to one of your questions. Later you can vote on any question or answer.